# D3 v4 Zoom x-Axis Zooming and Panning Issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I created a graph using D3 v4 that allows x-axis panning and zooming. I'm updating the graph differently when panning and zooming in order to decrease the amount of times we regenerate the graph.

**As For Panning**

When the user pans left or right i simply update the `transform` attribute as such:

`path.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)`.

It works well.

**As For Zooming**

I rescale the domain and re-generate the graph when the user zooms in order to achieve the desired behavior as such:

```
t = d3.event.transform;
xScale.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain()); //update xScale domain

xAxis =d3.axisBottom(xScale)...
focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);
usageAreaPath.attr("d", area); //area being a reference to the generator
usageLinePath.attr('d',line); //line being the name of the generator
```

The problem is, performing a pan after zoom or zoom after pan results in the graph jumping to different zoom levels. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or how to rebind the scale after zooming/panning to update the proper scale, but I have attached a JSBIN below:

http://jsbin.com/webowajola/edit?js,output

Comment: In D3, the zoom deals with the panning. So, you just need `.on("zoom", redraw);`.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado If I handle the panning with redraw i'll be regenerating the graph. I don't want to regenerate the graph, I just want to translate the graph according to the pan,i.e.`usageAreaPath.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);` but if there is a zoom then, I'd like to use the redraw contents. i.e. `usageAreaPath.attr("d", area); usageLinePath.attr('d',line);`

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I'm sorry for the confusion, is it clear what I'm asking?

Comment: How are we supposed to see the problem in your jsbin? How can we pan? How can we zoom?

Comment: @ConnorsFan is it not panning or zooming for you? via rolling the mouse  over the graph or grabbing the grab and dragging?

Comment: when you first load the graph, you can zoom up and down by scrolling the mouse wheel up and down.

Comment: OK, I see it now. Initially, the pan does not do much (only moves the curve up once). I have to zoom first to make the pan "work" afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

If you are updating the graph differently when panning and zooming in order to decrease the amount of times we regenerate the graph just add the check in the **zoomed** function as below,

```
function zoomed(){
    if(d3.event.transform.x !== 0 &&  d3.event.transform.y !== 0){
        redraw();
    }
}
```

[Here is the link to the updated working jsbin.](http://jsbin.com/xicurojuwa/1/edit?js,output)

I hope it will solve your graph regeneration problem.

Comment: I don't want to handle the pan with redraw, i'd like not to regenerate the graph if there is panning, i.e. `usageAreaPath.attr("d", area); usageLinePath.attr('d',line);`

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, is it clear what I'm asking?

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate problems with your code:

**1. Translate**

You used `.attr("transform", "translate( 0, 80)")` the wrong way. Remove all the `.attr("transform", "translate(0," + 80 + ")")` from your `<path>`, `<circle>`, axes and area and set the offset like this:

```
// Usage x-axis
var gX = focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + margin.top) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

// Focus Viewpoint
var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr('transform', "translate(" 
        + margin.left + "," + (margin.top + 80) 
        + ")"
     );
```

Doing this way, the whole chart is shifted downwards together in the `<g>`.

**2. panRight()**

You are moving the circles and the lines twice: First with the new scale, second with the `.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)`. So just remove following three lines

```
usageAreaPath.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
usageLinePath.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
circles.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
```

[Here the working jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gozogemico/edit?js,output)

**Edit**

I just realized, that the zoomed function is not working at all. The redraw function is called all the time during panning (also in my solution). Therefore the panning is executed twice. If the "if statement" in the zoomed function would work, the panRight() function would be necessary. So focus on this if/else statement. One option could be to distinguish between mouse wheel and drag event, e.g.
 `if(d3.event.sourceEvent.toString() === "[object MouseEvent]")`. So the redraw function will not be called during panning, but some scaling issues remain. Maybe [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/db6b4335bf1662b413e7968910104f0f) could help.

Answer (score -1):

i dont know whats is you aim for, i thing the answer above me it settle your thing, maybe you just didnt stop the event use `d3.event.defaultPrevented()` if you want stop the event

```
    function panRight(){
          d3.event.defaultPrevented()//use it so it will reset the event
          console.log('panRight',d3.event.transform);

          var new_xScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x2)
          gX.call(xAxis.scale(new_xScale));
          usageAreaPath.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
          usageLinePath.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
          circles.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
        }
//the result is normal ordinary chart
```

but if you playing with unremarking the `d3.event.defaultPrevented()` on redraw() the result is one weird chart

```
function redraw(){
  //d3.event.defaultPrevented()
  var domain, 
  minBuffer, 
  maxBuffer, 
  panDelta1,
  panDelta2,
  t;

  t = d3.event.transform;
  console.log('redraw',d3.event.transform);      
  // console.log(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
  // console.log(xScale.domain());
  //d3.event.defaultPrevented()
  xScale.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());

  xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickSize(0).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%b'));
  focus.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis);

  usageAreaPath.attr("d", area);

  usageLinePath.attr('d',line);



  //d3.event.defaultPrevented()
  focus.selectAll('.circle')
      .attr('cx', function(d) { return xScale(getDate(d)); })
      .attr('cy', function(d) { return yScale(d.kWh); })
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 80 + ")");


}
```